# rest response code is 200 but Content-Length is 0

Tags: java, rest, swagger, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I am trying to send a GET request to an api...but...

1. I am getting a response **code as 200 but Content-Length is 0**. This is happening when I am using my code in java (using Swagger code gen to generate Api Client code which internally handles the execution) I am just creating a wrapper around it to call an API using the client.
2. When I am doing this in **Postman**, everything seems fine...200 response code with Content-Length 196 (I am getting the response JSON back).
3. When I am trying this using **editior.swagger.io**, it is still working fine, 200 code with correct response body.

Below is the header that I am passing on Postman

Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: None

I am getting a response back from Postman (somehow postman is handling the internal work of compression)

Please guide to what I must do and do to make the post more descriptive.

Comment: Just ran through the same issue ? did you able to find the reason for that problem ? @sh4r4d

Comment: @AbhinavKumar Hey man, No I could not find any solution - because the problem was with my code - I was setting wrong URL end point through code, so request and response was OK, but there was not data which could come from wrong end-point. I will suggest you to check these thing - Check Content-Type, check URL end-point, check compression. Use Fiddlr to get traffic, that will give you a good idea of what is happening under the hood.

Comment: @AbhinavKumar also check Encoding